# Creating Property grid in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to create a property grid (the one which is similar to the one used in the resource editor in VS) using MFC. Does anybody whether there is any built in support in MFC for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need VS2008 and the feature pack, it's called [CMFCPropertyGridCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983759.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 with SP1 has [CMFCPropertyGridCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983759.aspx). But personally I still use Property Grid from .NET via C++/CLI wrapper class. It seems more convenient to me. You could compile only one file with `/clr` option and use MFC [CWinFormsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z4d86s2%28VS.80%29.aspx) in it.

Comment: Can I somehow use it with VS2003?

Comment: In VS2003 you could use PropertyGrid from .NET using CWinFormsControl.